# Are there relevant iterables with no length in Python?

Tags: python, iterable

In Luciano Ramalho's *Fluent Python*, an iterable is defined as an object in which the `__iter__` method is implemented, with no additional characteristics.

I am currently working out a tutorial for laymen in which I am trying to chunk the core concepts of Python to make programming more manageable for newcomers.

I find it easier to explain iterables and their utility for these people when I associate these objects with the concept of "size" (thus also `length`). By saying that "iterables are objects that have length" and thus tying in with the `len` function, I am able to naturally evolve the concept of loops and iteration with commonly used types such as the Standard Library `list`, `dict`, `tuple`, `str`, as well as `numpy.ndarray`, `pandas.Series` and `pandas.DataFrame`.

However, since now I know about the sole necessity for the `__iter__` method, there can be cases where the analogy with `len` fails. Ramalho even provides an impromptu [example](https://github.com/fluentpython/example-code/blob/master/14-it-generator/sentence_gen2.py) in his book:

```
import re
import reprlib

RE_WORD = re.compile(r'\w+')


class Sentence:

    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Sentence(%s)' % reprlib.repr(self.text)

    def __iter__(self):
        for match in RE_WORD.finditer(self.text):
            yield match.group()
```

As expected, any instance of `Sentence` is an iterable (I can use `for` loops), but `len(Sentence('an example'))` will raise a `TypeError`.

Since all the aforementioned objects are iterables **and** have a `__len__` method implemented, I want to know if there are relevant objects in Python which are iterables (`__iter__`), but do not have lengths (`__len__`) so if I can determine whether I just add a footnote to my tutorial or work out a different analogy.

Comment: `itertools` contains numerous examples.

Comment: Most of itertools, but particularly the three "infinite iterators" listed at the start, is built around the idea that you don't have to consider the length of the iterable: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html. Something with length is Sized, distinct from being Iterable: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html.

Comment: And in fact in many cases you don't *want* to know the length of an iterable. E.g., we use iterables for processing very large files in an efficient manner such that we don't need to load the entire thing into memory (or for processing network streams for which it's not possible to know the total "length").

Comment: And although a Collection is Sized, it doesn't really *matter* until you get to a Sequence, where you're accessing items by index and indexing beyond the length is an error. You can also have things with an *approximate* length: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__length_hint__. But it's not clear from what you've written what the current association is.

Comment: Awesome comments - seems you need to work out a different analogy, maybe start with the definition of iterate and iteration - leaving the *concept* of size/length for a different part of the instruction.

Comment: @wwii yup, seems like the case. I do understand that there is a fundamental difference between iterables and sequences/collections, as pointed out by larsks. Appreciate a lot the feedback though, guys, I'll rework the tutorial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A file has no length:

```
>>> with open("test") as f:
...    print(len(f))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object of type '_io.TextIOWrapper' has no len()
```

Iterating through a file like that in open iterates over lines, i.e. chunks of text delimited by newline characters. To know how many lines there are, the file would have to be read entirely and then iterated through - depending on the size of the file this could take a long time or the computer could run out of RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Iterators are ubiquitous iterables that usually don't offer a length:

```
>>> len(iter('foo'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    len(iter('foo'))
TypeError: object of type 'str_iterator' has no len()
```

```
>>> len(iter((1, 2, 3)))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    len(iter((1, 2, 3)))
TypeError: object of type 'tuple_iterator' has no len()
```

```
>>> len(iter([1, 2, 3]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    len(iter([1, 2, 3]))
TypeError: object of type 'list_iterator' has no len()
```